# Tagging PDF files on CD/DVD and opening them with the associated viewer

Tags: pdf, documents, tags

Simple thing. I have a lot - and I do mean, **A LOT** (if it was possible to colour this in red, it probably would be red as well) of PDF/dejavu/word/plain jpeg files; mostly articles from my professional domain. Memories fade, and the mind works on something else, and more often than not I find myself seraching *for that thing, I saw somewhere*.

Titles, as it is customary in academia, rarely give anything away in relation to the content.

Is there somewhere a system which enables me to keep those files with their original names (relating to our library system) but that **indexes** them, and **tags** them, so I can search by titles and by tags, and by clicking on the interesting work open them in their associated viewer.

That way I can burn one part of my personal library to a CD/DVD ... upon placing them in the drive, a *system(?)* would open, giving me the names of the articles on the disc, or the ability to view the tags, ... I find what I want, and it opens them in Sumatra/Adove/Foxit... ?

***Does such precious thing exists?***

Answer (score 0):

I had good experience with [tag2find](http://alternativeto.net/software/tag2find/) on Windows.
I used [zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) firefox extension.
Now, I'm using [google documents](https://www.docs.google.com).